# Backup virtual machines from VMware ESXi 5 to network storage

Tags: backup, esxi

I'd like to be able to create snapshots of the VMs on my VMware ESXi 5 server, which can be saved on external network storage. The solution should be free.

I already found [Trilead VM Explorer](http://www.trilead.com/Editions/), but the free version only works on the local machine.

Comment: i've already searched. found [link](http://www.trilead.com/Editions/), but the free edition backups the VMs on the local machine. i'm looking for something which works with the storage (if there's anything free)

Answer (score 1):

We use [GhettoVCB](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8760) this will do what you want and at no cost..

Answer (score 1):

VEEAM also provides a free solution to backup VMWare ESXi 5 server on an external storage.  They call it VEEAM Backup free edition.

Comment: VEEAM Backup and Recovery 6.1 is not compatible with ESX 5 and B&R 6.5 doesn't work on ESXi free versions

Comment: Please look for Veeam Backup Free Edition for VMware and Hyper-V new 6.5 from their website.  If you click on Product overview, you will see a PDF that lists supported Hosts environments:
•  ESXi 3.5–5.1
•  ESX 3.5 and 4.x

Answer (score 1):

Note: Free ESXi is not supported.

http://www.veeam.com/virtual-machine-backup-solution-free/download.html?ad=next_bottom

Comment: Link to info on same: http://www.veeam.com/virtual-machine-backup-solution-free.html?ad=product_list

Answer (score 0):

There is VMware [Data Recovery 2.0.2](http://www.vmware.com/support/vdr/doc/vdr_202_releasenotes.html) which works just fine. The only problem is that is works only with 5.0, but not 5.1 and 5.5.